# Running Actionscript Test from CommandLine

Tags: unit-testing, testing, actionscript

I have a .as Class which has some tests.

Now I am wondering is there any way I can run the tests using command line tools (provided by FLEX SDK)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a FlexUnit ANT Task for this.

http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Ant_Task
http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2010/02/02/run-flex-unit-tests-from-ant

Cheers